Issue when attempting to submit form with a ChoiceType using Symfony
I have the following code which does not work while attempting to submit the form:
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Status;
use App\Entity\Signal;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\ChoiceList;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
class SignalType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder

            
            ->add('actionPlan')
            ->add('actionPlanStatus', EntityType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'class' => status::class,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er): QueryBuilder {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'name',
            ])
            ->add('deadline')   
        ;
        $formModifier = function(FormInterface $form, Signal $actionPlanStatus = null){   
        };
        $builder->get('actionPlanStatus')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier){
                $actionPlanStatus = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $actionPlanStatus);
            }
        );
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Signal::class,
        ]);
    }
}

In the controller am using the following code:
public function yourAction(Request $request): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(SignalType::class);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // Handle form submission
        }

        return $this->render('_form.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

When testing, I get the following error:

App\Form\SignalType::App\Form{closure}(): Argument #2 ($actionPlanStatus) must be of type ?App\Entity\Signal, App\Entity\Status given, called in C:\laragon\www\abc\src\Form\SignalType.php on line 64

Could you please help idetifiying the root cause of the issue and how to fix it in order to let the dropdown option save into the database.
Expecting to have the form saved into the database.

You have an event on actionPlanStatus field, this field is configured to be a Status object.
On this line, you create the form modifier to use Signal (the parent object):
$formModifier = function(FormInterface $form, Signal $actionPlanStatus = null){};

What if you changed it to:
$formModifier = function(FormInterface $form, Status $actionPlanStatus = null){};

Or grab the parent object in the form event listener, something like:
$event->getForm()->getParent()->getData()


Thanks, I did update the code based on your recommendation however am now getting different error: An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'action_plan_status' cannot be null
